# WebPage in not opening in IE 9?

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, internet-explorer

I am facing a very unusual issue. When i am opening my webpage in IE 9 in Document and Browser mode both are IE9 it is not opening. But when i refresh that page it opens.

While for other browsers i am not facing this issue.

I am using Spring MVC and that page is a JSP page. I have tried various solutions given on web to set the compatibility for IE 9 but those fixes are nt working. Below is one of the link

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/649491/Enable-Compatibility-mode-in-IE

Comment: What is your page URL?

Comment: I am testing on my local and testing environment. That URL is not global URL.

Comment: Is there JavaScript in the page, or is the page huge?

Comment: Yes there is JS on this page and some of those are AJAX Calls but page is not that huge.  Does his impact the webpage?